# Yes/No : Is $f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $f_n(x)= \frac{x}{n}$  is uniformly   convergent on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

My attempt : i think yes, take $f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) =0$ because
 $\sup | f_n(x) - f(x) |= \sup\{\frac{1}{n}\}= 0$

Is its true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For every $n\in\Bbb N$,
$$\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:x\in\Bbb R\}=\sup\{x/n:x\in\Bbb R\}=\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not true. Take $\epsilon=1$. For each $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ you can take $n=n_0$ and $x=n_0+1$, and they satisfy $|\frac{x}{n}-0|\geq\epsilon$. So the sequence is not uniformly convergent in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence converges *pointwise* to $f(x)=0$. So if the sequence converges uniformly, then that's what it must converge uniformly to.

For any given $n$, how far away from one another are $f$ and $f_n$ (as measured by the supremum of $|f-f_n|$)? Can you increase $n$ so that this distance becomes arbitrarily small? That is the requirement for uniform convergence.