# Necessary and sufficient condition for $f_n$($x$) = $b_{n}x$+$c_{n}x^2$ to uniformly converge to zero

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Have been trying some questions on uniform and point-wise convergence of sequence of functions. Got stuck in this. I have to prove the following:-

Let ($b$$_n$)  and ($c$$_n$) be sequences of real numbers then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\lvert b_n\rvert$ $\lt$ $\infty$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\lvert c_n\rvert$ $\lt$ $\infty$ is not a necessary and sufficient condition for the sequence of polynomials f$_n$($x$) = $b$$_n$$x$+$c$$_n$$x^2$ to converge uniformly to $0$ on the real line.

I am trying to let $b$$_n$ = $\frac{1}{n}$ and $c$$_n$ = $0$

Now f$_n$($x$) becomes $\frac{1}{n}$$x$ which converges to $0$ point-wise. How can I prove it does so uniformly?

And also is this correct?

Comment: for $f_n=x/n$ look https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3374351/yes-no-is-f-nx-is-uniformly-convergent-on-mathbbr?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: A key question here: what is the domain? If it's unbounded, say, the whole real line $\mathbb{R}$ then $b_n=c_n=0$ is required, because you can make $x$ arbitrarily large compared to $b_n,c_n$.

Comment: @czzzzzzz..ok..so my example to contadict was wrong..any other example I could take?

Comment: @AlexR. yes..the domain is the  real line

Comment: take $b_n=c_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$, since $\sum |1/n|$ doesn't converges

Comment: @czzzzzzz thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take
$$b_n=c_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$\sum |b_n| \;\; and \;\; \sum |c_n|$$
are  convergent.

for all real $x$, 
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=0$$
the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ converges in a pointwise way to zero.

But, as a polynomial function
$$\sup \{|f_n(x)|\;, \; x\in \Bbb R\}=+\infty$$
since
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}|x+x^2|=+\infty$$
thus, the convergence is not uniform.